# Visual Studio custom toolbox component initialisation fails with error HRESULT: 0x80131040

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I've built a custom toolbox component, signed it and its dependencies with a StrongKey and finally registered the DLLs on Global Assembly Cache using gacutil. Therefore when I try to drag it from toolbox to any windows form, the instantiation fails with the following error:

> Failed to Create component 'Component1'. The error message follows: 'System.IO.FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm running Visual Studio 2012. Any advice of how to troubleshoot this issue?

1. Attaching a debug is something that I'm considering but I don't know how to do it.
2. Being able to see the full stack trace would help as well.

Thanks in advance